# Calling a global function from an inner class function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's a gist of my code

```
def global_func(text):
  ..do something with text..

class Data():
  def inner_func(some_text):
    # do something
    analysed_data = global_func("something")
    # do something else
```

I have gone through lots of questions, but they were on calling a class function from another class. I just want to call a global function from inner class.

The problem is I cannot access the global function from inner function.

How can I implement it ?

Comment: ... just like you have it there.

Comment: You may call global function exacly how you did it in your (incomplete) code snippet. What's detailed problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

Should be no problem as long as you send `self` with in-class function. This, for example, works:

```
def global_func(text):
  print("Global function prints %s" % text)

class Data():
  def inner_func(self):
    # do something
    analysed_data = global_func("something")
    # do something else

Data().inner_func()
```

Comment: What if the inner function uses an arguement ?

Comment: Then you just apply the argument after self. Check this out if you keep having troubles similar to this one: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that....

```
def addOne(x):
    return x+1
class Number():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def printAddedValue(self,x):
        print("Value inside is: ", self.value)
        print("Here we called the global function")
        print(addOne(x))

num = Number(3)
num.printAddedValue(6)
```

Output:

```
Value inside is:  3
Here we called the global function
7
```